# How to detect postgresql stored procedure language support?

Tags: php, postgresql

How can I detect on a production server which languages are available for stored procedures?

I can run sql queries from php and I have phppgadmin on the production server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the [`pg_catalog.pg_language` system table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-language.html):

> The catalog `pg_language` registers languages in which you can write functions or stored procedures.

So just some normal SQL is all you need:

```
=> select * from pg_catalog.pg_language;
 lanname  | lanowner | lanispl | lanpltrusted | lanplcallfoid | laninline | lanvalidator | lanacl 
----------+----------+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+--------
 internal |       10 | f       | f            |             0 |         0 |         2246 | 
 c        |       10 | f       | f            |             0 |         0 |         2247 | 
 sql      |       10 | f       | t            |             0 |         0 |         2248 | 
 plpgsql  |       10 | t       | t            |         11571 |     11572 |        11573 | 
(4 rows)
```

The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-language.html) should help you interpret the various columns.

Comment: Thanks! I found it just now, but you were 1 min faster :D